# How can a command crash the shell it runs from?

Tags: command-line, bash, crash

I am running some tests in an android emulator. I launch them from the command line:

```
npm run start:e2e
```

and once in a while, the command crashes so hard that the terminal window closes abruptly. If I am running it in the IDE, then that crashes too.

I am not trying to solve the problem, merely to understand how such a thing happens.

Even if I make the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exit
```

and source it in the shell, the terminal window does not close.

Is there some way to post-mortem such a crash?

Comment: Many ways possible for "crashing the shell" some of which might be imposed from outside the shell process itself e.g. system OOM killer ... But internally the exit call e.g. `bash -c 'exit'` will terminate the sub-shell forked for that script ... While the parent-shell running in the terminal will still be running ... To kill the parent-shell from a sub-shell, you can do e.g. `bash -c 'kill -9 $PPID'` ... Where the environment variable `$PPID` holds the parent process ID of the current sub-shell.

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with 5.15.0-60-generic kernel.